# SQLAlchemy + pymssql - cannot connect to sql db from jupyter kernel gateway docker

Tags: docker, sqlalchemy, pymssql, jupyter-kernel-gateway

I have 'sql_helper' that connect to my sql server.

```
 db_connection = 'mssql+pymssql://{user}:{password}@{server}/{db}'.format(
 user=db_user, password=db_password, server=server_name, db=db_name)

 engine = sa.create_engine(db_connection)
```

When running it locally it works well.

Then, I have added it to my jupyter kernel docker image.
This is the **docker file**

```
# start from the jupyter image pre-installed
FROM jupyter/datascience-notebook

# install the docker 
RUN pip install docker

# install the pymssql
RUN pip install pymssql

# install the kernel gateway
RUN pip install jupyter_kernel_gateway

# install the configuration helper
COPY configuration_helper-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl /tmp/configuration_helper-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
RUN pip install /tmp/configuration_helper-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl

# install the sql helper
COPY sql_helper-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl /tmp/sql_helper-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
RUN pip install /tmp/sql_helper-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl

# update enviroment variable
ENV AM_I_IN_A_DOCKER_CONTAINER Yes

EXPOSE 1433 
EXPOSE 5000 

# run kernel gateway on container start, not notebook server
EXPOSE 8888
CMD ["jupyter", "kernelgateway", "--KernelGatewayApp.ip=0.0.0.0", "--KernelGatewayApp.port=8888", "--KernelGatewayApp.api=kernel_gateway.notebook_http", "--KernelGatewayApp.seed_uri"]
```

When running notebook with the following command

```
docker run -it --rm -p 1433:1433 -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" --net=host --name ml_docker_rule_Get_prediction_rule_2 -v C:\Notebooks:/data jupyter-kernel-gateway  jupyter kernelgateway --KernelGatewayApp.api='kernel_gateway.notebook_http' --KernelGatewayApp.seed_uri='/data/AOI_app_1.ipynb' --KernelGatewayApp.ip=0.0.0.0 --KernelGatewayApp.port=8901
```

I am getting the following error

```
Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (TESLADEVSQL01:1433)
```

Any help how should I run it from docker would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem, instead of using host name need to use sql ip

Comment: I had similar problem, and it was fixed with using IP instead of hostname. Alternatively you can ping the host to get the full hostname (for example, if I ping my `db_host` I get `db_host.some_network.LOCAL`). It achieves the same but may be more robust to IP changes.